# How to make my Flash video primary and HTML5 video Secondary?

Tags: flash, html

Hi i need to make a video page. i used a flash player and implemented the videos on the pages. now my client needs that, the same page have to work with ipads, i know that we have to use html5 video player for that.

My question is in case eventhough html5 video supportable player available that should play the flash content first. in case it will not run the flash player then it should run the html5.

that mean my flash player is primary player and my html5 is secondary. any one give me the best suggestion to do this? i am looking for some simple way and without plugins...

thanks for advance.

Comment: I'm curious now.  Why do you not want the HTML5 video by default with the Flash video as fallback content?

Answer (score 0):

Are these the clients own videos?

If they are, get them to buy a Vimeo pro account, upload the video's to there, you can tie them to their domain if necessary and vimeo's embed code will do all this for you.

Comment: I'm sure there is other ways, but why re-invent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

I would put your flash in place on the page then using javascript at page load use the detection techniques [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#video) to check for iOs video support and replace the flash with the video element.